# Boto3 : Wait for the whole zip file to be uploaded to lambda

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, boto3

I was trying to create a command line tool to upload zip files to lambda. Basically boto3 provided direct zip upload function. But the response is instantaneous. It doesnt wait till the zip file is completely uploaded to lambda. So is there anyway to find the complete status of file upload? Like when it got finished, whether the uploaded was succesful

the boto3 function code looks like this

```
def run_lambda_upload():
response = client.update_function_code(
FunctionName='test_command_line_zip_upload',
S3Bucket='test',
S3Key='test_lambda.zip'
Publish=True
)

print response

run_lambda_upload()
```

It would be helpful if someone could provide a guidance on this

Comment: You can poll on getFunction.

Comment: @balki I am completely new to python. Could you tell me a bit more like what it means

Comment: I don't see `ZipFile ` being passed to `update_function_code`.

Comment: @helloV that was a mistake when I wrote this question, the original code has the zipfile. I have edited that in question now

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is update the code from s3 bucket 'test', It doesn't pick the file locally from your system and hence the response is instantaneous. To do that you need to use the ZipFile param and send the contents of zip file to that parameter.